# What does a high self-time in "java.lang.Thread.run" in a HotSpot view signify?

Tags: java, performance, jprofiler

Following is the screen shot of the "Hot Spots" of "CPU Views" of JProfiler when I probe my application at the sampling mode. The top of the stack (76% of CPU usage) is occupied by "java.lang.Thread.run".

My question is which threads are these? Are these the threads which are responsible for other hotspots showing from second position and below (Marked in the green box)? Or are these the threads which are doing some back ground tasks like garbage collections and all (The corresponding methods are not visible in the list of hot spots)?

[image]

Comment: Why is it getting negative votes? Could you please clarify?

Comment: `java.lang.Thread.run` is a method, normally called from `Thread.start` as the 'work to do'. The profiler is grouping methods together. Methods and threads are different concepts and although the method is 'related to' threading it does not imply that 'threading' is itself a problem (threads run code in many other methods too!). That being said, I don't have a good explanation for that output and I would expect other high self-time methods :}

Comment: @ArnabBiswas Are you starting a lot of short-lived threads? Then most of the time would be used to start the thread and not to do actual work

Comment: @IngoKegel It's a Netty based application. Both Netty and my business logic uses Thread pooling. So, that possibility is very less.

Comment: @ArnabBiswas How are your filters set? Are there unprofiled classes that are invoked between the thread start and the profiled classes? All that time would end up in the Thread.run node. You could try to disable all filters to see the complete call tree.

Comment: @IngoKegel Yes, I have filters. That's a good suggestion. I can try that.

Answer (score 1):

Most webservers (Java and otherwise, including JBoss) follow a "one thread per request" model, i.e. each HTTP request is fully processed by exactly one thread. This thread will often spend most of the time waiting for things like DB requests. The web container will create new threads as necessary.

These threads are not responsible for garbage collection activity. The JVM always executes a GC in dedicated threads, the “GC threads”. Whenever GC threads are active, they compete against the actual “application threads” for available processors and thus CPU time.

To answer your question, yes all tasks corresponding to user requests are considered over here. In other words, your CPU is spending 76% of its time processing user requests.

All nested method call times are captured in the first hotspot you have shown in the image.

Comment: The methods which are appearing with in the green box (down the stack) are also being executed by the user threads which you have mentioned. So, I am not sure whether the self time of "java.lang.Thread.run" include the self time of those methods as well?

Comment: No, they are not included. If a function shall have nested calls then you can expand the '+' icon to see their respective self times.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this part is responsible for JEE/JSE internal stuff like unpacking JARs. JProfile filters is out by default. If this hidden RAM/CPU consumption takes the majority of your resources it means, your application itself doesn't really consumes any or just doesn't do any meaningful job ;-)

Disable filter (Session Setting -> Filter Setting) and restart the profiling. You will see what happens behind "Thread.run".